# ggplot2: easy way to plot integral over independent variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm integrating a function `f(t) = 2t` (just an example) and would like to plot the integral as a function of time `t` using

```
awesome_thing <- function(t) {2*t}
integrate(awesome_thing, lower=0, upper=10)
```

However, I would like to plot the integral as a function of time in ggplot2, so for this example the plotted points would be (1,1), (2,4), (3,9), ..., (10,100).

Is there an easy way to do this in ggplot (e.g., something similar to how functions are plotted)?  I understand I can "manually" evaluate and plot the data for each `t`, but I thought i'd see if anyone could recommend a simpler way.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12429538/1898580

Comment: Dear Marat, thanks so much for your help! Unfortunately, that is not what I want.  Essentially, i'm trying to plot the integral of the function evaluated at each value of t, from 0 to 10.  So in the above example, the plotted points would be (1,1), (2,4), (3,9), ..., (10,100).  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you're likely to be better off evaluating outside of `ggplot2` and then plotting.

Comment: Thanks Ben, was hoping there was some quick n' dirty way, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `ggplot` solution and `stat_function`

```
 # create a function that is vectorized over the "upper" limit of your
 # integral
int_f <- Vectorize(function(f = awesome_thing, lower=0,upper,...){
    integrate(f,lower,upper,...)[['value']] },'upper')


ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,10)),aes(x=x)) + 
   stat_function(fun = int_f, args = list(f = awesome_thing, lower=0))
```

Comment: Thanks mnel!  this gives an error however "Error: unexpected '}' in "}"".  What am I missing here?  thanks!

Comment: mnel, I need to integrate over a (VERY) long time period and am getting an error "error in integrate(f, lower, upper, ...) : maximum number of subdivisions reached".  Can you tell me how I can add a subdivisions parameter here?  I've tried adding it to the function(), integrate(), and list() like for f and lower, however it throws another error "Error in f(x, ...) : unused argument (0)
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default"

Comment: @Thomas, Naming the argument in the list works for me... `ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,10)),aes(x=x)) + 
   stat_function(fun = int_f, args = list(f = awesome_thing, lower = 0, subdivisions = 1e5))`

Comment: Thanks again mnel, you're correct, it works!  my error was i was adding the argument in int_f as well.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not ggplot2 but shouldn't be difficult to adapt by creating a dataframe to pass to that paradgm:

```
 plot(x=seq(0.1,10, by=0.1), 
      y= sapply(seq(0.1,10, by=0.1) ,  
            function(x) integrate(awesome_thing, lower=0, upper=x)$value ) , 
         type="l")
```

The trick with the integrate function is that it retruns a list and you need to extract the 'value'-element for various changes in the upper limit.