# How to shade part of a density curve in ggplot (with no y axis data)

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I'm trying to create a density curve in R using a set of random numbers between 1000, and shade the part that is less than or equal to a certain value. There are a lot of solutions out there involving `geom_area` or `geom_ribbon`, but they all require a `yval`, which I don't have (it's just a vector of 1000 numbers). Any ideas on how I could do this?

Two other related questions:

1. Is it possible to do the same thing for a cumulative density function (I'm currently using `stat_ecdf` to generate one), or shade it at all?
2. Is there any way to edit `geom_vline` so it will only go up to the height of the density curve, rather than the whole y axis?

Code: (the `geom_area` is a failed attempt to edit some code I found. If I set `ymax` manually, I just get a column taking up the whole plot, instead of just the area under the curve)

```
set.seed(100)

amount_spent <- rnorm(1000,500,150)
amount_spent1<- data.frame(amount_spent)
rand1 <- runif(1,0,1000)
amount_spent1$pdf <- dnorm(amount_spent1$amount_spent)

mean1 <- mean(amount_spent1$amount_spent)

#density/bell curve
ggplot(amount_spent1,aes(amount_spent)) +
   geom_density( size=1.05, color="gray64", alpha=.5, fill="gray77") +
   geom_vline(xintercept=mean1, alpha=.7, linetype="dashed", size=1.1, color="cadetblue4")+
   geom_vline(xintercept=rand1, alpha=.7, linetype="dashed",size=1.1, color="red3")+
   geom_area(mapping=aes(ifelse(amount_spent1$amount_spent > rand1,amount_spent1$amount_spent,0)), ymin=0, ymax=.03,fill="red",alpha=.3)+
   ylab("")+ 
   xlab("Amount spent on lobbying (in Millions USD)")+
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1000,100))
```

Comment: I think in this case it may be easier to either calculate the density outside of ggplot, or use th eplot internals. If `p` is your basic density plot: `d <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] ;  p + geom_area(data = subset(d, x > rand1), aes(x=x, y=y), fill="red") `

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple of questions that show this ... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429333/how-to-shade-a-region-under-a-curve-using-ggplot2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points), but they calculate the density prior to plotting.

This is another way, more complicated than required im sure, that allows `ggplot` to do some of the calculations for you.

```
# Your data
set.seed(100)
amount_spent1 <- data.frame(amount_spent=rnorm(1000, 500, 150))

mean1 <- mean(amount_spent1$amount_spent)
rand1 <- runif(1,0,1000)
```

Basic density plot

```
p <- ggplot(amount_spent1, aes(amount_spent)) +
          geom_density(fill="grey") +
          geom_vline(xintercept=mean1)
```

You can extract the `x` and `y` positions for the area to shade from the plot object using `ggplot_build`. Linear interpolation was used to get the `y` value at `x=rand1`

```
# subset region and plot
d <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

p <- p + geom_area(data = subset(d, x > rand1), aes(x=x, y=y), fill="red") +
          geom_segment(x=rand1, xend=rand1, 
                       y=0, yend=approx(x = d$x, y = d$y, xout = rand1)$y,
                       colour="blue", size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: There are a dozen questions asking the same thing and this answer is the cleanest.