# Shade area for data points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data points:

```
c(1553872.0297353, 3987850.7333411, 3149751.04758742, 139690.256184131, 
2659359.58444917, 4424034.10243952, -164716.863161922, 1032117.65430564, 
1012016.7065469, 4846572.29657933, 3226129.15792111, 4017430.43881163, 
3828193.63192272, 3829708.57524592, 1332388.79071537, 2089023.58090538, 
1644671.18495059, 4460304.42245758, 3371828.92991641, 4113191.0440754, 
3113751.73357746, 617900.379054606, 1317373.8428064, 6300890.66407368, 
3296661.03616896, 4118518.49087673, 4542392.60001633, 2195633.29577509, 
3704255.4295885, 3256168.15662825, 3859226.70793027, 4302788.70683497, 
1212610.90730169, 1100156.02674204, 3877506.61645749, 2679633.27812409, 
3873805.93153843, -260211.296112984, 3245236.76979178, 1287142.02860096, 
940739.460417479, 2994090.66052949, 4945187.39388016, 4245739.22159749, 
1834826.91901863, 4007125.98655838, 2441363.58320388, 3927976.3634389, 
3311368.65232602, 7075557.77947983, 3243219.14157882, 2517657.51519752, 
3171624.62320739, 3402860.88835126, 4842785.56583616, 3855876.39565095, 
2405788.12178841, 2880195.38919339, 3290479.8769342, 5214395.40981439, 
4303049.42485616, 2195917.90046817, 3177092.87433431, 2380356.21216434, 
3387837.07527694, 1638340.56836534, 4622169.45155907, 2364584.07782942, 
3739518.62696525, 3297125.04237121, 1406550.84702262, 4524851.84638035, 
5300405.1815232, 2307646.3613227, 2102213.83460057, 2520455.84518903, 
4988206.87073815, 2121162.4699674, 4603996.13556966, 4977903.73829612, 
5327575.83245304, 4454316.67896575, 3115751.54495466, 3802810.69212559, 
-719107.265338242, 879256.548205465, 3757467.72037339, 1397266.77760947, 
2683252.17093566, 2267063.20041564, 3507007.12497479, 2671586.12385416, 
2883476.2559073, 1646404.25714463, 1480966.75076908, 6262630.29895663, 
2270844.80306551, 4490116.75684258, 3300223.17061254, 1470747.71921301
)
```

I would like to generate a plot, and shade the area of the respective density plot where the x axis is negative. Or also with histogram. Something like this:

```
   ggplot(mapping=aes(res_cost))+geom_density(fill="skyblue")
```

But in this case I just want the shaded area from 0 to the left. I also would like to include to show in the plot the percentage of shaded area. I am not fresh with all of these I know that I could use the quantile function but I dont remember very well these concepts.

[image]

I was following a post suggested,

```
plt<-ggplot(mapping=aes(res_cost))+geom_density(fill="skyblue")

d<-ggplot_build(plt)$data[[1]]
p <- plt + geom_area(data = subset(d, x <= 0), aes(x=x, y=y), 
 fill="red") +
  geom_segment(x=0, xend=0, 
               y=0, yend=approx(x = d$x, y = d$y, xout = 0)$y,
               colour="blue", linewidth=3)
```

[image]

But something that I dont know how to correct is first. How to get the percentage of the area under the curve that is with red? and why I cant see the borders, I expect the complete kernel density, but there are not extremes.  Additionally, what if I need to apply the same idea but with bar plots or histograms, because doing like this I got read polygons.
[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at other posts on shading part of the density? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215748/how-to-shade-part-of-a-density-curve-in-ggplot-with-no-y-axis-data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429333/how-to-shade-a-region-under-a-curve-using-ggplot2https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points

Comment: Yes I tried, just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most concise way of doing this is precalculating the density and plotting it as a `geom_area`

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- within(as.data.frame(density(res_cost, n = 1e4)[c("x", "y")]), z <- x < 0)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_area(aes(x, y, fill = z), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("skyblue", "red3"), guide = "none")
```

[image]

And the proportion of the curve that is red is

```r
sum(df$y[df$z])/sum(df$y)
#> [1] 0.02912582
```

In other words, 2.9%.

To do the same with a histogram we can do:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(res_cost, fill = after_stat(x < 0))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("skyblue", "red3"), guide = "none")
```

[image]